# Amazon SageMaker could not get a response from the endpoint

Tags: python, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I have built an anomaly detection model using AWS SageMaker inbuilt model: random cut forest.

```
    rcf = RandomCutForest(
    role=execution_role,
    instance_count=1,
    instance_type="ml.m5.xlarge",
    num_samples_per_tree=1000,
    num_trees=100,
    encrypt_inter_container_traffic=True,
    enable_network_isolation=True,
    enable_sagemaker_metrics=True)
```

and created the endpoint:-

```
    rcf_inference = rcf.deploy(
              initial_instance_count=4, instance_type="ml.m5.xlarge",
              endpoint_name='RCF-container2',
              enable_network_isolation=True)
```

But when I tried to get the prediction using the endpoint I am running into the following error:-

```
    results = rcf_inference.predict(df.values)

    ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received server error (0) from model with message "Amazon SageMaker could not get a response from the RCF-container2 endpoint. This can occur when CPU or memory utilization is high. To check your utilization, see Amazon CloudWatch. To fix this problem, use an instance type with more CPU capacity or memory."
```

I have tried with larger cpu instance but still I am getting the same issue. I guess the issue is functional.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking the CloudWatch Logs to see if there is any other error that could point to the issue.

I work for AWS and my opinions are my own.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).